# How to create a Kubernetes Deployment with the 'kubectl run' command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

As per an [article](https://medium.com/icetek/preparing-for-ckad-aa00a94b0db7) I read, while using the '*kubectl run*' command,

- --restart Always creates a deployment,
- --restart Never creates a pod
- --restart OnFailure creates a job

However, when I try that on my Minikube installation it is creating a resource of kind: Pod

```
k run ngingx --image=nginx -o yaml --dry-run=client --restart Always
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: ngingx
  name: ngingx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: ngingx
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Has the feature been deprecated or am I doing something wrong ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this

`kubectl create deployment ngingx --image=nginx -o yaml --dry-run=client`

Nope the `restart: Always` does not create pod or deplyoment it's about the container restart policy which is used for restarting container if pod crashes it tries restart.

Comment: Thank You. But still trying to understand if the feature I mentioned was there before and no longer works ?

Comment: i think before kubernetes 1.18 or 1.17 the kubectl cli-tool did create a pod by default and a deployment when you would add the option --restart=Always. However, since then kubectl only creates pods with kubectl run and for everything else you use kubectl create $resourcename